# android adding to spinner causes crash due to filenotfound exception

Tags: android, file, spinner

I am using a spinner that gets it information from a text file, which is created/ modified in another activity. When I open the activity that uses this method it crashes saying the exception of filenotfound. Though i have run the activity that creates the file and added data into the file previously. I tried both in my android device and on emulator.

Here is the method that loads the data into the spinner:

```
public void loadOpp() throws FileNotFoundException {            
    BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            openFileInput("Opponent")));
    String inputString;
    List<String> final2 = null;               
    try {
        while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            final2.add(inputString);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Spinner spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, final2);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);        
}
```

and here is the method that creates the text file in the other activity:

```
public void onSubmitClick(View view) {
    EditText mEdit;
    String filename = "Opponent";
    mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.oppName);
    String string = mEdit.getText().toString();
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
      outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
      outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
      outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I understand the error, but i do not understand why it would cause the error if the file was created, so maybe the file isn't being created in the first place. Any thought on how to fix this error, and how to avoid it in the future/ what am i doing wrong basically.

Comment: Maybe you should start by checking if the file is actually created by using something like if(file.exists()){//do something}

Comment: try adding the extension  of the file String filename = "Opponent.txt";

Answer (score 0):

It could be that when you are creating the file your either not creating it where you think you are or you are trying to create it where there really is no directory. You could try using

```
if(f.createNewFile()){
    System.out.println("FILE CREATED "+f.getAbsolutePath());
}else{
        System.out.println("FILE NOT CREATED "+f.getAbsolutePath());
                     }
```

And that would tell you that your creation of the file failed or not